# Trying to execute the ng-change using semantic UI and angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, semantic-ui

I am trying to load a dropdown with angularjs and semantic UI with the following code

```
<div id="state" class="ui search selection dropdown">
  <label for="state">Estado</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="state">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Selecione o Estado</div>
  <div class="menu" ng-model="state" ng-change="loadCity()">
    <div ng-repeat="state in states" class="item" data-value="{{state.ID}}">{{state.NAME}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
```

But the event is not called.

When I use the code below it works:

```
<select id="state" class="ui search selection dropdown" ng-model="state" ng-init="loadState()" ng-change="loadCity(state.ID)">
  <option ng-repeat="state in states" value="{{state.ID}}">{{state.NAME}}</option>
</select>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an issue other people have encountered. Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1913

> I found a way to solve this issue on angular side using some 1.3 magic. It's not the best way of doing this but it works.
>
> It can simply be solved by using the formController and a watch.
>   I updated the plnkr. Note that i use underscore.js to find the array index of the control inside the form.
>
> The rest is pure angular and some jquery.
>
> http://plnkr.co/edit/eDOej3zJ0bwQ1xyX1LDI?p=preview

Look at the section starting with:

    `app.directive('select'`

Comment: In the example provided it uses select tag not the tag div from semantic ui. Any other example?